# Docker and shared memory optimization?

Tags: docker, performance

Imagine you would run a bunch of services say based on the same Tomcat image.

Would Docker optimize memory usage for identical memory segments and reuse these patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is discussed in some detail in [issue 7950](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7950)  The conclusion seems to be that:

- Depending on your storage configuration, the kernel page cache may be used if multiple containers are accessing the same file (e.g., see [OverlayFS and Docker Performance](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#overlayfs-and-docker-performance)).
- You may be able to enable [Kernel same-page merging](https://openvz.org/KSM_(kernel_same-page_merging)#Enabling_memory_deduplication_libraries_in_containers) through use of of the [ksm_preload](https://vleu.net/ksm_preload/) tool.